# WordPress - цикл категорий с постами

Tags: wordpress

Доброго времени суток, у меня такой вопрос. Не могу понять, как построить цикл вывода категорий в WordPress. Нужно повторять блоки, в которых будет название категории и все посты, которые принадлежат данной категории. Вручную прописывать название категории не подходит, потому что я хочу, чтобы данная конструкция была автоматизирована и повторялась.

Comment: Сударь, похоже вы потеряли все запятые и случайно подцепили букву Ы в цЫкле. Вас очень сложно понять

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко зачем запятые в цыкле? )))

Comment: В цикле они может и не нужны, а вам бы не помешали

Answer (score 0):

Сначало получаеш список категорий, а внутри выводиш ещо один цикл с постами. 
Пример:

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
) );

foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    $cat_id = $category->term_id; // ID Категории
    $cat_link = get_category_link( $cat_id ); // Линк на категорию
    $cat_name = $category->name; // Имя категории
    $cat_desc = $category->description; // Описание категории
    $cat_count = $category->count; // Общее количество постов в категории
    // Цикл вывода постов из текущей категории, устанавливаем параметры
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5, // Количество постов на вывод
        'cat' => $cat_id // ID категории, из какой выводить(текущая в цикле)
    );
    $posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $posts_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $posts_query->have_posts() ) : $posts_query->the_post();  
//  Тут можно оперировать с выводом постов, подключать темплейт например
    endwhile; 
    endif;
}
```